# Why browser sends burst of request at the moment of tab close?

Tags: sockets, http, browser

Here is log from my custom web server:

```
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_RDINGS!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

Client Reader Thread 8 waiting for client input...
CTHD8: req orig: GET /upd HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-ali

CTHD7: req orig: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-alive

Client Reader Thread 7 waiting for client input...
CTHD7: req orig: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-alive

Client Reader Thread 7 waiting for client input...
CTHD7: req orig: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-alive

Client Reader Thread 7 waiting for client input...
CTHD7: req orig: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-alive

Client Reader Thread 7 waiting for client input...
CTHD7: req orig: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.141
Connection: keep-alive

Master Writer update operation: WRT_UPDATE_HEAD!
Master Writer waiting for updates on Web Queue...
Master Writer update operation: WRT_DEFAULTS!
```

It uses `EventSource` to send real time updates to browser. So `WRT_RDINGS` is normal operation. But at the moment when I close site tab it sends loads of requests non-stop. After that my server is gets shut down by `SIGPIPE` (writing to closed socket, probably). Browser is MS Edge in this case. Is this normal behavior for browser and why it happens? Does all browsers behave like that or only Chromium based?

P.S. It's normal for browser to open 2 sockets for 1 tab – one for base HTML page and other for `EventSource`? I guess it can open as many as it would like, right?

Comment: No, it is not normal behaviour for a browser, but I bet the browser is behaving normally, but your server is not. If you don't believe me there is always Wireshark

Comment: @user253751 It's funny how browser constantly sends "keep-alive" in header requests, but never actually behaving adequately and actually reusing connections (although I send him keep-alive in responses). Instead browser opens new socket for each new request (when sending form, for EventStream, etc.) and never closes opened sockets, while never sending new requests on them. When I close connection from server browser lags and displays blank page dropping all connections. This is some total madness............

Comment: I also want to add that this requests spam only happens when closing tab. If I close browser entirely, there is no spam.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue... Turns out I was misled by my own poor buffer placement and also very stealthy `read(2)` special feature that is never mentioned in any tutorials and only very indirectly mentioned in man-page.

Start of my reader threads was like this:

```
    while(1)
    {
        char buff[2048];
        res = read(sock, buff, 2048);
        if(res < 0)
        {
            delClient(s);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
```

So, I assumed that `buff` will get destroyed at the end of loop and recreated each time. It was really stupid, I know, because its local variable and it's not inited with zeroes automatically like global or statics. I don't know what I was thinking. But anyways, It actually didn't contain any junk data, but It retained past request from client in this thread, for example: `GET /upd HTTP/1.1`.

When I remade loop start to this:

```
while(1)
{
    char buff[2048];
    res = read(sock, buff, 2048);
    if(res < 0)
    {
        delClient(s);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    else if(res == 0)
    {
        printf("Client Reader Thread %d received empty request... Terminating!\n", sock);
        delClient(s);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

I got this result instead of request spam:

```
Client Reader Thread 7 received empty request... Terminating!
Client Reader Thread 8 received empty request... Terminating!
Client Reader Thread 9 received empty request... Terminating!
.......
```

And finally started to see real picture... `buff` was reusing it's last request when `read(2)` actually received nothing, 0 bytes. And I was sure it's browser spamming me with requests.

In documentation its super vague and not clearly written:

> On files that support seeking, the read operation commences at
> the file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number
> of bytes read.  If the file offset is at or past the end of file,
> no bytes are read, and read() returns zero.

Maybe it works differently with sockets that with normal files... Documentation from C# `Receive` method is more clear and maybe that's exactly how `read(2)` works with sockets too:

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown
> method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method
> will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

Also I could have just `memset`-ed buff to 0 every time, but I guess, checking one `int == 0` costs much less CPU that `memset`-ing 2048 bytes!

Edit: this socket is also in blocking mode, so it was very surprising for me to learn that it can suddenly stop blocking and start spamming zeros.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `read`. You seem to have discovered that if you don't put any data in an array in C, it can have leftover data in it!